# Is 'all UNIX applications programs' a typo by Kernighan/Ritchie?

Tags: application, terminology

I'm reading [The C Programming Language (2nd edition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie. I the preface to [the first edition](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/page/n9/mode/2up), there is a line that reads:

> The operating system, the C compiler, and essentially all UNIX
>   applications programs (including all of the software used to prepare this book) are written in
>   C.

I'm having a hard time parsing this snippet "UNIX applications programs". To my understanding application and program are synonyms. If there were an and in the middle, it would make sense. If application were singular, again it could kind of make sense.

Am I missing something? Is there a distinction between program and application?

Comment: I disagree that answer to this will be opinion based.  The fact that this is a term of art in computer science that the questioner isn't familiar with is not a subjective matter of opinion.  And it's a fair question from computer science novices.  We don't reject the many questions from non-English speakers that (for examples) abuse "codes" and "terminal" for _program_ and _shell_.  We should not reject one premised upon a similar misunderstanding, especially as it asks for what the correct understanding is.

Comment: @JdeBP so what's the technical difference between "application programs" and "application**s** programs"? Can you give any example where using the singular or the plural form of a noun adjunct changes the *meaning* of the phrase?

Comment: @TomasZubiri [Don't forget your teethbrush](https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2012/jul/05/mind-your-language-nouns)

Comment: That's a distraction fallacy that is irrelevant to the point at issue, which is the vote to close this for being subjective and the charge that this is not a good and useful question to ask.

Comment: Amazingly relevant article! If I had read "application programs" I would have understood programs that sit at the highest level of abstraction, that interface with the user directly, instead of say network protocols or compilers. "applications programs" along with "applications program" seems to imply that a single program is related to multiple applications, instead of application being an adjectival noun of program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Application programs", and application software in general, is software that is intended to be used by end users.  The typesetting system `troff`, alluded to in the quote, was a prime example of this as its development [helped justify the cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troff#History) for developing the Unix operating system at Bell Labs in around 1971 (only a couple of years before the rewrite of Unix in C). `troff` was later rewritten in C for the Sixth Edition of Unix in 1975 (together with implementations in C of the Thompson shell, the brand new `awk` language and many other tools), and the C book came out in 1978 (the 2nd edition from 1988 also contains the same quote).

Wikipedia says this about [Application Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software):

> In information technology, an application (app), application program or application software is a computer program designed to help people perform an activity. Depending on the activity for which it was designed, an application can manipulate text, numbers, audio, graphics and a combination of these elements. Some application packages focus on a single task, such as word processing; others, called integrated software include several applications.

As for the "s" at the end of "applications" in "applications programs", it's simply indicating that a program, or the set of programs, may have several applications.  You sometimes see the same "s" in terms like "applications technology", "applications developer", etc. (in fact, my own job title is officially "systems developer", with the same kind of plual "s" at the end of "systems"). Later in the book, you will also find "applications software" used about the tools that a Unix system provides.

The fact that the term "application" is more common today than "application program", and that "application" and "program" are largely synonymous nowadays does not mean that "application program" is redundant if you want to emphasize the end users as the target audience for the program.

Note also that "program" in itself does not necessarily mean something whose intended audience is end users (in contrast to users who support or maintain the product). "Program" by itself is more strongly connected to the meaning "the source code", and Merriam-Webster [defines "program"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/program) as

> a sequence of coded instructions that can be inserted into a mechanism.

... and the Cambridge Dictionary [defines it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/program) similarly as

> a series of instructions that can be put into a computer in order to make it perform an operation

Comment: @roaima I inserted a section that I hope addresses this.

Comment: I think this is just reading way too much into a typo (in a preface, which few read diligently anyway, making chances of typos being noticed lower than usual). Is the same phrase repeated anywhere else in literature by Kernighan or Ritchie?

Comment: @muru In the same book, the term "applications software" also occurs. I don't think it's a typo.

Comment: I was hoping more for a source like the UNIX Programmer's Manual Volume 2, which has the phrase `"applications" programs` (including the quotes, which is far more likely to be deliberate)

Comment: @muru The quoted text also survives into the second edition of K&R.

Comment: Excellent response, thanks! I'm glad I asked. @muru I was translating it into spanish, so the depth of terminology usage is appreciated.

Comment: muru, the notion of (roughly) dividing programming into _systems programming_ and _applications programming_ is not a typographical error, and can be found in most decent encylopaedias of computer science and good introductions to the subject.  They can be found from Robert M. Graham's 1975 _Principles of Systems Programming_ to Harry Henderson's 2009 _Encyclopedia of Computer Science and Technology_.