# What does Rob Pike consider 'system research' in his essay?

Tags: historical-unix

I'm not sure what does Rob Pike consider 'system research' in his essay (that can be found [here](http://doc.cat-v.org/bell_labs/utah2000/utah2000.pdf)).

Is he referring to operating systems?

What's a system to him?

Comment: Nowhere in that "essay" does he use the phrase "system research"; it's "system**s** research", everywhere. Why are you "correcting" him? See also the comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586988/is-all-unix-applications-programs-a-typo-by-kernighan-ritchie#comment1093443_586988)

Comment: @UncleBilly Wow, you must be really fun to hang out with.

Comment: Be more explicit if you really have anything to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always ask Rob Pike directly!

I think that in this essay, “system” is everything in a computer, or even a system composed of multiple computers: that includes the operating system, but also hardware, programming languages, how the user interacts with the system, how applications work together, how computers work together, etc. Thus Rob Pike deplores that

> If systems research was relevant, we’d see new operatingsystems and new languages making inroads into the industry,the way we did in the ’70s and ’80s.

but also that

> Even into the 1980s, much systems work revolved around new architectures (RISC, iAPX/432, Lisp Machines).  No more.  A major source of interesting problems and, perhaps, interesting solutions is gone.

and that

> Only one GUI has ever been seriously tried, and its best ideas date from the 1970s.  (In some ways, it’s been getting worse; today the screen is covered with confusing little pictures.) Surely there are other possibilities.  (Linux’s interface isn’teven as good as Windows!)

Trying to pigeonhole the notion of a system is itself part of what the essay encourages readers *not* to do:

> Go back to thinking about and *building systems*. Narrowness is irrelevant; breadth is relevant: it’s the essence of *system*.

Bear in mind that Rob Pike, after working on Unix, went on to develop Plan 9, which is quite unusual compared to current systems (but will feel somewhat familiar to users of Lisp Machines, Smalltalk environments etc.).

Comment: @user431397 right, I was thinking more of the user experience, with the central role of acme, plumbing etc., and of the greater discoverability of the system as a whole (*i.e.* see something you want to change and figure out what to change).